# Spring Security cannot redirect the address correctly on the first successful login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Recently I tried to use Spring Security in my project, but when I started the server for the first time and successfully logged in, Spring Security redirected the page to "/" instead of the address I expected "/admin/to/main/ page.html". When I open the login page for the second time, Spring Security can work normally.

I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

My Spring Security configuration for successful login is as follows（
My Spring Security version is 4.2.10.RELEASE）

```
            .loginPage("/admin/to/login/page.html") 
            .loginProcessingUrl("/security/do/login.html") 
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/to/main/page.html")  
            .usernameParameter("loginAcct")   
            .passwordParameter("userPswd")      
            .and()
            .logout()                    
            .logoutUrl("/security/do/logout.html") 
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/to/login/page.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

Which is as it should work. This is the [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#defaultSuccessUrl(java.lang.String)) behavior of the `defaultSuccessUrl` configuration method you are using.

If you want to force the use of the URL use the other [`defaultSuccessUrl`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#defaultSuccessUrl(java.lang.String,boolean)) method, with this you can indicate if it should be forced or not.

```
defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/to/main/page.html", true)
```